# Android - Unable to add to RemoteMediaPlayer queue by calling queueInsertItems() multiple times

Tags: android, google-cast

I am using the CastCompanionLibrary to add items to a RemoteMediaPlayer queue by calling queueInsertItems() from VideoCastManager.java like so:

> queueInsertItems(unique_items, MediaQueueItem.INVALID_ITEM_ID,
>   customData);

The first few requests go through, but after a few times, I start getting a TransientNetworkDisconnectionException and all subsequent requests return a [status code 2103 (REPLACED)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes). At this point, I can no longer add items to my media queue until I disconnect and reconnect back to the cast device.

Here is a copy of my logcat:

```
 01-28 00:24:56.750 7185-7185/com.google.sample.cast.myplayer D/ccl_VideoCastManager: [v2.7.1] > queueInsertItems returned. Status code: 2103
 01-28 00:24:56.789 455-469/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=5534(5) createSurf 0x41449a94 (1x1),1 flag=4, Uoast
 01-28 00:24:56.805 463-1700/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] acquire WakeLock flags=0x2000000a > tag=WindowManager uid=1000 pid=463
 01-28 00:24:56.891 7185-7189/com.google.sample.cast.myplayer D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRE> NT freed > 1843K, 28% free 18679K/25856K, paused 4ms+16ms, total 201ms
 01-28 00:24:57.008 28371-12138/? D/CastSocket: [controller-0688 API] IOException encountered. > Tearing down the socket.
                                            java.io.IOException: invalid message size (138391) received.
                                               at com.google.android.gms.cast.c.o.n(SourceFile:457)
                                                at com.google.android.gms.cast.c.o.j(SourceFile:686)
                                                at com.google.android.gms.cast.c.v.b(SourceFile:35)
                                                at com.google.android.gms.cast.c.w.run(SourceFile:103)
                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 01-28 00:24:57.016 28371-12138/? D/CastSocket: [controller-0688 API] shutdown with reason=2
 01-28 00:24:57.016 28371-28371/? D/CastDeviceController: [controller-0688 API] onDisconnected; > socketError="2 IO Error"
 01-28 00:24:57.023 28371-9680/? D/CastDeviceController: [controller-0688 API] > onSocketDisconnectedInternal: socketError="2 IO Error"
 01-28 00:24:57.023 28371-9680/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0688 API] finishDisconnecting; > socketError="2 IO Error", mDisconnectStatusCode=SUCCESS
 01-28 00:24:57.023 28371-9680/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0688 API] listener.> onDisconnected(NETWORK_ERR
```

One thing I notice in my logcat is that CastSocket API keeps shutting down with reason 2 due to an invalid message size. I'm not sure what that means or why it's happening. But could somebody kindly explain what is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many items are you adding?

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you for getting back to me. I am adding 50 per request. Does the Api have a size limit on the total number of items I can add or a per request total?

Comment: Since it is going to be a bit longer to answer your question, I am going to write an Answer rather than a comment

Comment: Thank you so much in advance. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each request/api is transferred using a generic message and each message has a max size; you should assume that the payload can't get beyond 64k but keep in mind that a message is made of a bunch of things and they easily add up. The error you are seeing about invalid message size makes me think you are running into that issue. Try sending less items. Also, note that with the current structure, it is not enough to break the queue of, say, 500 items into 20 messages with 25 items in each; although you can do that, you will run into issues shortly after since all the update messages that your receiver sends to connected senders also follow the same size limit, so they will fail if they need to report on a huge number of item. It might be best, given the current limitations, if you could somehow manage the queue in a way that at each moment in time, the receiver doesn't hold too many items in memory, while, at the same time, it knows how to get more items from your (cloud) backend when it needs to. You may also consider doing some more management on your sender side to avoid pushing too many queue items into a queue on the receiver and unload some queue items and add some new ones to keep the total in-memory number low.Finally, try to reduce the info for each item that you send to the receiver to as little as possible; for example, your receiver may not need to have all the fields/metadata available for an item, or given the UI structure on the TV, it may not be able to show any, say, description beyond 100 characters, so trim the info to what the receiver absolutely needs. Then, on the sender side, you can retrieve full info/metadata about each item from the cloud directly so if a second sender joins the party, it gets minimal data from the receiver and then it fills the gap by going to the cloud directly rather than relying fully on the metadata that the receiver can send it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ali, that helps to clarify alot. I will try to be mindful of those constraints. Yes, i do have many items in the RemoteMediaPlayer queue when this happens and i think you are right. The problem seems to have to do with the reciever trying to send back messages to connected senders once my queue contains more than ~500 total items

Comment: Ali, could you recommend any resources or examples that demonstrate how to customize the receiever to get around the current limitation? I would ultimately like to be able to create massive playlists and queue them on the receiever if possible. The cloud method looks promising, but don't know where to begin and if there is already some foundational work I can leverage. Thanks.

Comment: I am not aware of any library or sample; one reason for that is that any good solution should work with the cloud and every application/provider has its own cloud so abstracting that out may not be something easy or even useful to everyone so that is why there is no sample; in our samples we try to stay generic.

Comment: That makes sense. When I have time, I will look into it. I suppose, in the meanwhile I will display a Toast that says max items reached if a user tries to add more than max amount. Please let me know if you ever go down the route of implementing some type of solution or if an update gets released in the future to address this issue. I would gladly comtribute.